# Extract string between fields from begin to end and end to begin of the line - space delimited - shell commands

Tags: regex, shell, extract

I have one logfile that is space delimited file. The structure is this

Mon Oct 05 23:17:52 2015 0 10.0.0.1 3989728 /dir/file name.txt X X X X acct proto 0 *

I want to be able to extract the filenames, which sometimes for my lucky contains a space in its name. e.g "file name.txt"

I cannot simply cut this using the field position, because of that space that sometimes appears in the name of the files.

The way I was thinking of doing this was getting what is between the field 8 from left to right and field 8 from right to left.

But I cannot think of anything to help me with that.

Does anyone had to do it before and can shine a light.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this should work: $regex = "~\/(?: a-z)+?\.txt~i";

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to attempt without a larger data, but here is a rough solution that will discard the tenth field if it does not match a specified pattern. (This only works if there is a single whitespace `' '` in the file name):

```
#!/bin/sh

STORE1=$( echo "Mon Oct 05 23:17:52 2015 0 10.0.0.1 3989728 /dir/file name.txt X X X X acct proto 0 *" | awk '{print $9}' )

STORE2=$( echo "Mon Oct 05 23:17:52 2015 0 10.0.0.1 3989728 /dir/file name.txt X X X X acct proto 0 *" | awk '{print $10}' )

# if the tenth field matches the string "X" discard it
if [ "$STORE2" != "X" ]
then STORE1="$STORE1 $STORE2"
fi

printf "%s" "$STORE1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick test with python:

```
import re

txt = "Mon Oct 05 23:17:52 2015 0 10.0.0.1 3989728 /dir/file name.txt X X X X acct proto 0 *"
print re.search("\d+(\.\d+){3}\s+\d+\s+(.*)(\s+\S+){8}",txt).group(2)
```

Yes, I realize this is not shell, but the regular expression will pick up anything between the (ip address, integer) and before the last 8 fields as you were attempting.  Just use the regex and apply it to your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Mon Oct 05 23:17:52 2015 0 10.0.0.1 3989728 /dir/file name.txt X X X X acct proto 0 *" 

sed -r 's#.*/([^.]+\.[A-Za-z]*).*#\1#' logfile.txt
```

The regex could be explained as follows:

- `.*/` Matches every character until the last slash.
- `([^.]+\.[A-Za-z]*)` Matches everything from there and up to the first dot, followed by alphabetic characters. This is the filename. The text matched is captured by the group.
- `.*` Matches the rest of the line.

The whole line is therefore substituted with `\1`, the text captured by the group 1 (the filename), and output to `logfile.txt`.

Some assumptions were made: the file must always have a slash from its path, the filename must have only one dot for the extension, and the extension consists of only alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the inputs. I thought a bit more about it and used AWK to get that done.

Looping file content from the field I want to last field minus 8.

cat file | awk '{out=""; for(i=9;i<=NF-8;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}'